# Convert output of count method into a percentage value

Tags: python, pandas

If I run .count() on an object:

```
animals = all_vals[['Dog','Cat','Mouse','Snake']].count()
```

and receive this output:

```
animals
Out[49]:
Dog      173
Cat      13
Mouse    42
Snake    359
dtype: int64
```

How do I then get the percentage occurrence of each animal? Can I send the output of .count into another method?

Comment: Can you divide the results by len(all_vals)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
print (animals)
Dog      173
Cat       13
Mouse     42
Snake    359
Name: animals, dtype: int64

print (100 * animals / animals.sum())
Dog      29.471891
Cat       2.214651
Mouse     7.155026
Snake    61.158433
Name: animals, dtype: float64
```